# Error in expand_dims(X_train, axis = 2) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I tried to use keras in R to do deep learning

```
trend_train <- ts(global_GDP[1:28,c(3)], start=c(1981), end=c(2008))
lstm_num_timesteps <- 5
X_train <- t(sapply(1:(length(trend_train) - lstm_num_timesteps), 
                function(x) trend_train[x:(x + lstm_num_timesteps - 1)]))
X_train[1:5, ]
X_train <- expand_dims(X_train, axis = 2)
```

When try to use expand_dims(), it showed error as follows

```
Error in expand_dims(X_train, axis = 2) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Couldn't figure out what's going on here as there is no wrong with the expand_dims(). Anyone could help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue trying to build an LSTM using Keras library in R.

expand_dims() seems to be a function from **kerasR** library https://rdrr.io/cran/kerasR/man/expand_dims.html

If you are using **keras** (not kerasR package), this function is not available. This corresponding function in keras package is [k_expand_dims](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/keras/versions/2.1.2/topics/k_expand_dims)

I also realised that this only works with keras 2.1.2. I had to upgrade from v 2.0.9 to make this work.

Hope this helps.